# Bind ViewModel properties to data that's returned in a List from LINQ formatted in a table then Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

The requirements for this goal:

1) Query Entity table A and return a list of Id's that are **NOT** present in Entity table B.

2) Create a form with the returned Id's from Entity table A and combine with the properties in Entity table B formatted in a table and associate Entity Table B properties with the Id's.

Table A = SampleLog

TableB = FPDrinkingWater

**The ViewModel**

```
public class AddDrinkingWaterModel : FPDrinkingWater
{
    public int SID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Location is required.")]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public short? Replicate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CollectionDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? CollectionTime { get; set; }
    public string Collectors { get; set; }
    public string Chlorinated { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public List<int> Data { get; set; }
}
```

**The GET Controller Action**

```
//GET
 public async Task<ActionResult> AddMultiDrinkingWaterLog()
 {
    var context = new DbContext();

    var sampleList = (from s in context.SampleLog
                   where s.ProgramId == 5 && !context.FPDrinkingWater.Any(m => (m.SID == s.Id))
                   select s.Id).ToList();
    var modelCollection = sampleList.Select(s => new AddDrinkingWaterModel
        {
            Data = new List<int> { s }
        }).ToList();               

        return PartialView("_AddMultiDrinkingWaterTable", modelCollection);
 }
```

This returns all of the correct Id's and associates the `AddDrinkingWaterProperties` with the Id's returned from the LINQ query. **Note** the relationship between SampleLog and FPDrinkingWater is one to many. SampleLog.Id = FPDrinkingWater.SID foreign key. I can post the individual Entities if requested.

**The View** _AddMultiDrinkingWaterTable (Ajax Is needed due to some information being displayed after the action completes)

```
@model List<MyApplication.Areas.FP.Models.AddDrinkingWaterModel>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(actionName: "AddMultiDrinkingWater", routeValues: null, 
htmlAttributes: new { id = "AddMultiDrinkingWaterForm", @class = "form-horizontal" },
 ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions
{
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
UpdateTargetId = "AddMultiDrinkingWatersContent",
LoadingElementId = ajax
}))
{
<div style="overflow: auto; height:auto">

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <table id="AddMultiDrinkingWaterTable" class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstOrDefault().Id)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstOrDefault().Location)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstOrDefault().Replicate)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstOrDefault().CollectionDate)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstOrDefault().CollectionTime)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstOrDefault().Collectors)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstOrDefault().Clorinated)</th>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstOrDefault().Comments)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)

            {
            <tr>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Data.First().Id)
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Data.First().Id)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Location)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Replicate)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].CollectionDate)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].CollectionTime)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Collectors)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Clorinated)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Comments)</td>
                </tr>
            }
         </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Adding...">Add All</button>

}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        makeDataTable('AddMultiDrinkingWaterTable')
    });
</script>
```

**The POST Controller action**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddMultiDrinkingWater([System.Web.Http.FromBody] AddDrinkingWaterModel addDrinkingWater)
 {            
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         foreach (var sample in addDrinkingWater.Data)
         {
            if (addDrinkingWater.Location != null)
            {
                 //assign the SID the Id value from the SampleLog
                 addDrinkingWater.SID = sample.Id;
                 // perform database Save action.
             }
          }
      }
      else
      {
          InvalidState();
      }
return RedirectToAction("AddMultiDrinkingWaterLog");
}
```

All research that I've done has shown how to add multiple records returned in a list, not creating a view from combining a list and viewmodel properties.
When the data is entered in the view, single records cannot be sent. It's either all records or no records. When the data reaches the controller the model is completely null. It may be with something related to the view model being in a list. I feel that there may be a better way of doing this as well, and I'm open to suggestions and improvement.

Comment: The model in the view is `List<AddDrinkingWaterModel>`, therefore the parameter in the POST method must also be `List<AddDrinkingWaterModel model>`, not a single `AddDrinkingWaterModel` (and why do you have the `System.Web.Http.FromBody` attribute on you POST method - that need to be removed)

Comment: And since you only ever include a hidden input for the first `int` value in your `List<int> Data` property, (using `HiddenFor(m => m[i].Data.First().Id)`) then that would never bind back to that property

Comment: So I removed the `FromBody` from the method and changed the Id to be  `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Data)`. If I enter data for one row it does not post. It only posts when all records have data. For what it's worth, this is a screenshot of the table I'm trying to create. The user can enter data in 1 or all rows to create new records in the FPDrinkingWater table.
https://imgur.com/a/B8hiWzI

Comment: You cannot bind a collection to an input (you would need a `for` loop to generate a hidden input for each item in the collection). And did you change the parameter to `List<AddDrinkingWaterModel>`? And you have a `[Required]` attribute on the `Location` property so `ModelState` will always be invalid unless you enter values for all records

Comment: But if a use can create just one record, why are you showing multiple records?

Comment: In the view I have the Hidden element for the Id though? And yes I updated the parameter to accept a list. What I'm trying to do is similar to the link you posted on another one of my questions [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/post-an-html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) but I'm having one of the columns generated by a LINQ query

Comment: [This is an example but with add instead of edit](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/editing-multiple-records-using-model-binding-in-mvc/). Also one column being generated from a LINQ list. I also removed the `[Required]` from the location and it still invalidates the model state.